# Passing parameters is not working in Quartz 1.6

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I try to pass parameters using quartz(1.6) api in ServletA

```
        JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
        map.put("date", "20151101");
        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.triggerJob(jobName, groupName, map);
```

When I trigger JobA, it work. 
But I can't get parameter in JobA from folloing code. 
map is null.

```
    JobDataMap map = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    String date = (String) map.get("date");
```

Do I miss something important?? **Thanks for help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter maps can be passed to the execution from the job or/and the trigger. In your solution you explicitely try to get the job's datamap (at `ctx.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap()`) , which is `null` because you set your parameters via the trigger.

You can use the [`getMergedJobDataMap`](http://javadox.com/org.opensymphony.quartz/quartz/1.6.1/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getMergedJobDataMap%28%29) of JobExecutionContext to get a parameter map merged from both:

```
JobDataMap map = jobExecutionContext.getMergedJobDataMap();
String date = (String) map.get("date");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you so much~~~